# UITableView Dynamic Row Height Without Using AutoLayout

Tags: uitableview, ios7

I am supporting iOS 7 and I am not using autolayout. Is there a way I can have dynamic height for cell labels doing it this way?

Thanks

EDIT:

Here is the code I am using to define a dynamic height in iOS 7, it seems I can get it kinda working with auto layout but it cuts off the last cell at the bottom, it is weird.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    var cell = offScreenCells.objectForKey("gcc") as? GalleryCommentCell
    if cell == nil {
        cell = commentsTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("GalleryCommentCustomCell") as? GalleryCommentCell
        offScreenCells.setObject(cell!, forKey: "gcc")
    }

    let comment :GalleryCommentInfo = commentResults[indexPath.row]

    setCellCommentInfo(cell!, data: comment)

    cell!.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(commentsTable.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(cell!.bounds))

    cell!.setNeedsLayout()
    cell!.layoutIfNeeded()

    let height = cell!.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
    return height + 1
}

func setCellCommentInfo(cell :GalleryCommentCell, data :GalleryCommentInfo) { 
    cell.commentDate.text = data.galleryCommentDate

    cell.comment.text = data.galleryComment
}
```

Comment: Start by reading the docs for `UITableViewDelegate`.

Comment: I tried multiple solutions, nothing works. The last cell seems to get cut off, just the bottom part of it. I can post code, I have even tried it with autolayout.

Comment: Update your question with what you tried and explain what issues you are having.

Comment: It seems adding contentInset to to the bottom of my table resolved the cut off issue but not sure if that is the most efficient way of doing it.

Answer (score -1):

In your custom cell implement method like this:

```
+ (CGFloat)heightForContactName:(NSString *)name
{
    CGFloat height = 0.0f;
    if (name) {
        CGFloat heightForText;
        // Calculate text height with `textBoundingRect`...
        height += heightForText; 
    }
    return height;
}
```